# ¿Can refer to a map property in his declararion?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

For example, is posible to do something like this (this fails):

```
def map = [ property: 1,
            propertyPlusOne: map.property + 1]
```

Of course, it's posible to do so:

```
def map = [:]
map.property = 1
map.propertyPlusOne = map.property + 1
```

But all in the declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `with` declaration:

```
def map = [ : ].with {
    property = 1
    propertyPlusOne = property + 1
    it
}

assert map.propertyPlusOne == 2
```

Though something like ruby's [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) (or [@timyates' extension](https://github.com/timyates/groovy-common-extensions/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/bloidonia/groovy/extensions/ObjectExtensionMethods.groovy)) is slightly cleaner:

```
def map = [ : ].tap {
    property = 1
    propertyPlusOne = property + 1
}

assert map.propertyPlusOne == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally not.

You have to define and initialize your `map` var first, to be able to set values:

```
def map = [ property: 1 ]
map += [ propertyPlusOne: map.property + 1]
```

I'm not sure what you are up to, but it might be worth checking the `withDefault()` method.